# Does the "Lockdown Mode" only protect Apple apps? If you mainly use Open Source alternatives, does this feature offer nothing?

Tags: ios, security, ventura, privacy

I enabled Lockdown Mode today. The [advertising](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212650) sounds very good:

> What is Lockdown Mode?
>
> Lockdown Mode is an optional, extreme protection that’s designed for
> the very few individuals who, because of who they are or what they do,
> might be personally targeted by some of the most sophisticated digital
> threats. Most people are never targeted by attacks of this nature.

Then I took a closer look at the KB article and I don't use these services at all, but Open Source alternatives.

This mode does not bring me anything? I use Lockdown Mode on iOS and macOS. Is there any hidden benefit?

Comment: why downvotes without a comment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some protections only apply to the services listed. There are some that apply to your computer overall, though.

Additionally, even if you don't use the services, protections against incoming data are still relevant.